# LDAP path problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am working with LDAP and I am new to this.

Is there a way to get the domain when you only know the username, password, servername

I am trying to do this:

```
string ldapPath = "LDAP://serverName";
string uid = username;
string password = pwd;
string qry = String.Format("(uid={0})", uid);
string adsPath = String.Empty;

try
{
    DirectoryEntry nRoot = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);

    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(nRoot, qry);
    SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();

    if (sr != null)
    {
       // we want to retrieve the DN like this: "uid=myuser,ou=People,dc=findlay,dc=edu
       ldapPath = sr.Path; //update where we will bind next
    }
```

This does not work unless I change

```
 string ldapPath = "LDAP://serverName";
```

to

```
 string ldapPath = "LDAP://serverName/DC=mydomain,DC=com";
```

Any help..??

Thanks

Edit rootDSE

```
string defaultNamingContext;

using (DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://serverName/rootDSE", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous))
{
    defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
}
```

I too feel this is the solution but it is currently not working for me.. please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find BASE DN from LDAP directory context object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777067/find-base-dn-from-ldap-directory-context-object)

Comment: @user207421 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777067/find-base-dn-from-ldap-directory-context-object is for java, not c#

Answer (score 2):

`RootDSE` is not server-bound - try this:

```
string defaultNamingContext;

using (DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous))
{
    defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Or if you're on .NET 3.5 and newer, you could use `PrincipalContext` instead, which can be constructed without any path - it will just pick up the default domain you're connected to:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

You should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here (that's .NET 3.5 and newer):

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Comment: how-to get ***datatype and Range-Upper*** from AD attribute ? e.g ***initials*** attribute

Answer (score 2):

If :

```
using (DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://serverName/DC=mydomain,DC=com") 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

works, have you try  (without being anonymous):

```
string defaultNamingContext; 

using (DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://serverName/rootDSE") 
{ 
    defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString(); 
}
```

or

```
using (DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://serverName/rootDSE", user, password) 
{ 
    defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString(); 
}
```

It works for me, from a computer not in the domain.

Comment: how-to get ***datatype and Range-Upper*** from AD attribute using PrincipalContext ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try like   this

// Method call

```
string netBiosName = GetNetBiosName(LDAP://CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=<DomainName>,DC=<local|com>,  "<userName"", "<password>");
```

// Method call

// Method Definition

```
private string GetNetBiosName(string ldapUrl, string userName, string password)
{
   string netbiosName = string.Empty;
  DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapUrl,userName, password);

   DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);
   searcher.Filter = "netbiosname=*";
   searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

   SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
   if (results.Count > 0)
   {
    ResultPropertyValueCollection rpvc = results[0].Properties["CN"];
    netbiosName = rpvc[0].ToString();
   }
   return netbiosName;

}
```

pls take a look at this link [for more info](http://geekswithblogs.net/Tariq/archive/2009/07/30/133813.aspx)

Comment: problem is i dont know the domain name. i just know the servername, username and password.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the domain by just calling RootDse.

Comment: `DirectoryEntry("LDAP://serverName/rootDSE") `